# Remove null items from a list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

What is the best way to remove null items from a list in Groovy?

ex: `[null, 30, null]`

want to return: `[30]`

Comment: Funny that nobody asked how the nulls ended up in the list in the first place.  Seems like you might be addressing the symptom rather than the problem.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

here is an answer if you dont want to keep the original list

```
void testRemove() {
    def list = [null, 30, null]

    list.removeAll([null])

    assertEquals 1, list.size()
    assertEquals 30, list.get(0)
}
```

in a handy dandy unit test

Comment: +1 for the most readable solution (reads like: "remove all nulls")

Answer (score 149):

Just use minus:

```
[null, 30, null] - null
```

Comment: One can also use [null, 30, null].minus(null).That seems more readable to me. Version with '-' reminds about SBT operator abuse.

Answer (score 54):

The findAll method should do what you need.

```
​[null, 30, null]​.findAll {it != null}​
```

Comment: ​`[null, 30, null]​.findAll {it}​` will do.

Comment: Thomas, findAll {it}​ will remove 0 as well as null. And if that is what you want then you might as well just do a findAll()

Answer (score 20):

I think you'll find that this is the shortest, assuming that you don't mind other "false" values also dissappearing:

```
println([null, 30, null].findAll())
```

> `public Collection findAll()` finds the items matching the `IDENTITY`
> Closure (i.e. matching Groovy truth).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> def items = [1, 2, 0, false, true, '', 'foo', [], [4, 5], null]
> assert items.findAll() == [1, 2, true, 'foo', [4, 5]]
> ```

Answer (score 12):

This can also be achieved by [grep](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#grep(java.lang.Object)):

```
assert [null, 30, null].grep()​ == [30]​
```

or

```
assert [null, 30, null].grep {it}​ == [30]​
```

or

```
assert [null, 30, null].grep { it != null } == [30]​
```

Comment: New location for docs: [grep](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#grep(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 2):

Simply `[null].findAll{null != it}` if `it` is null then it return false so it will not exist in new collection.

Comment: `assertEquals [], [0, false , null].findAll{it}`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is `[null, 20, null].findResults{it}`.

Answer (score 2):

This does an in place removal of all null items.

```
myList.removeAll { !it }
```

If the number 0 is in your domain you can check against null

```
myList.removeAll { it == null }
```